# OracleClient command - best practices around USING and disposing of command

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection-pooling

According to the MSDN documentation for the OracleClient.OracleCommand:

```
Public Sub ReadMyData(ByVal connectionString As String)
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT EmpNo, DeptNo FROM Scott.Emp"
    Using connection As New OracleConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New OracleCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As OracleDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Try
            While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0) & ", " _
                   & reader.GetInt32(1))
            End While
        Finally
            ' always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

The OracleCommand is not wrapped in a Using block.

Question:  Should it be?  OracleCommand inherits from DbCommand, which implements IDisposable.

I'm looking at code that does the following, and we're having problems with implicit cursors not getting closed:

```
     Dim cmd As OracleCommand = createCommand("some sql")
     ds = GetDataSet(cmd)
     cmd.Dispose()
     cmd = Nothing
```

GetDataSet looks like:

```
  Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter()
  Dim ds As New DataSet()

  Using conn As OracleConnection = GetOpenConnection()
     cmd.Connection = conn
     da.SelectCommand = cmd
     da.Fill(ds, 0)
     cmd.Connection = Nothing
  End Using
  da.Dispose()
  da = Nothing
  Return ds
```

Is this going to leak resources?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you should explicitly close your connections in your code, because depending on the provider there is some additional work that gets done when you call the Close method

Comment: But according to the MSDN code, this isn't needed.  

And if I have a Using cmd = new OracleCommand()  block, then do I need to explicitly close it?

Comment: Disposing of a command does not mean that the associated connection is closed. Remember that a connection can be used by several commands.

Comment: @Conrad  This is wrong.   Using statement is best known practice as it implements the IDisposable interface.  Also, using Close() is bloated code as whether the using is used or calling Dispose() , the Dispose method implicitly ALWAYS calls Close() method.

Comment: @Tom - I have come across some providers (whether by accident or design) that do not close the Close() method in the dispose. Got my fingers burnt on practically

Comment: @Conrad - Since I haven't truly seen this happen, I may have been too harsh / ignorant.  As I jump around doing contract work I end up with several Phone and F2F interviews every year and it seems that every other interview or so I hear "When the 'Using' is being implemented, will it always close/dispose connections?"  I end up saying "NO" and on the phone there is a pause, and in F2F a deer in headlights look (them thinking ..time for next candidate) .. That is when I kindly burst their bubble with the answer "If there is a stackoverflow then NO it WILL absolutely not get called!

Answer (score 1):

How are you determining that the implicit cursors are open and that that is a problem?  The reason I ask is that calling the "Close" method does not actually close the connection.  It just lets the pool know that it is no longer being used and can be reallocated somewhere else.  This is done for performance reasons because actually physically opening a connection is expensive.  The same connection will be reused many times and may well remain open even after calling "Close"  so if you are using some Oracle tools to peer into the connections it may be leading you astray.

I have never seen any reason to explicitly dispose of the command object.  It is just a collection of parameters and other info.

If you use a using block as you have, there is absolutely no need to call "Close" or "Dispose" explicitly in code.  That is the whole point of the using block.  It protects you from forgetting to call Close since that is exactly what it does for you.

Comment: select 
  a.value, 
  s.username, 
  s.sid, 
  s.status,
  s.schemaname,
  s.machine,
  s.logon_time,
  s.state,
  s.serial#
from 
  v$sesstat a, 
  v$statname b,  
  v$session s
where 
  a.statistic# = b.statistic#  
  and s.sid=a.sid
  and b.name = 'opened cursors current'
  and s.type='USER'
order by s.username;

We have max. cursors set to 300, but we keep getting ORA-01000 error.  Monitoring show that 100 cursors are getting opened each request (it's a summary page, queries lots of tables) but they're never closed, so my assumption is that we're not closing or disposing of something.

Comment: Are you calling GetDataSet in a tight loop?  Releasing the connection to the pool is an asynchronous operation and if you are in a tight loop it will probably grab a new connection for each iteration because it isn't releasing them fast enough. 

Wow, that seems like a lot of connections for one page.  Might be a design issue there.

Comment: Definitely a design issue, but it surfaced the problem.  Solution was to wrap each new OracleCommand in a using, and each DataReader in a using - problem solved.  MSDN documentation looks to be incorrect.